# Merge Replication on not all of columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I want to configure a merge replication between two table which are have a special column with different values. It means the replication shouldn't synchronize the special column. I configured this replication (push mode) but when i configured the special subscription. the related table was changed and not published columns was removed from subscriber's table?
what's the solution for my problem?